# Show confirm dialog before create app widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I want to show some confirmation dialog when the user has dragged a new app widget. If the user cancels the dialog, the app widget is not added (or deleted).

I have implemented custom code when deleted using `AppWidgetProvider.onDeleted`, but have no idea how to get "added" event so that I can show a confirm dialog, and reject app widget creation when necessary.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AppWidgetProvider` java file, under onUpdate method create a dialog and show.

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {

  // ..... your code

   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,You wanted to make decision");

      alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
              // add widget
         }
      });

      alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // dont add widget
         }
      });

      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialog.show();


}
```

Comment: Good. Small note: I think `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` needs to be `new AlertDialog.Builder(context)`